# VueJS single file component briefly showing SVG unstyled

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a really simple Vue single-file component (using Vue 2.4.2) that includes an SVG image using a set of predefined SVG symbols and work perfectly.

I notice that the icon is briefly shown unstyled before the component (non-scoped) style is applied. Important to note that:

- When including the scss in our main .scss file, the problem does not occur
- Using `v-cloak` with has no effect
- Occurs on latest Chrome, FF and Safari (MacOS)

**Q: I can obviously use the workaround of including it in the main scss file, but I was wondering if this is SVG-styling specific or if a delay is normal when using component-style?**

My component (additional scss omitted):

```
<template>
  <i class="icon" v-if="symbol" :class="{'icon-spin': spinning}">
    <svg>
      <use v-bind:xlink:href="symbol"></use>
    </svg>
  </i>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  name: 'Icon',
  props: {
    icon: {type: String},
    spinning: {type: Boolean, default: false}
  },
  computed: {
    symbol () {
      return this.icon ? '#' + this.icon : ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style lang="scss">

@import '../../style/variables';

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: $icon-size;
  height: $icon-size;
  line-height: 1;

  svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    fill: currentColor;
  }

  ...
```